# Resize MapView on tap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I have mapView to my ViewController in storyboard. It has 4 constraints ( Height equals: 300 , align trailing to: Safe Area, align Leading to: Safe Area and Align Top to: Safe Area. I created tapGestureRecognizer to my mapview. I want to resize mapview to full screen when user tap on a map.

```
    private func setupMapView() {
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mapTouchAction(gestureRecognizer:)))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func mapTouchAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    }
```

I tried to change height constraint to screen Height but it is not what i want ( view is positioning in the middle of the screen and then its resizing , this is not what i am looking for) I used this code inside my mapTouchAction().  I want my view to resize with animation to the bottom view ( screen height). How can i achieve it? should i use CGAffineTransform or maybe theres another way? Any ideas?

```
   for constraint in self.mapView.constraints {
        if constraint.identifier == "mapViewHeightConstraintID" {
            constraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        }
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy solution for my problem. I only change my mapView frame. So inside tapGesture function mapTouchAction(_: UITapGestureRecognizer) i have

```
@objc func mapTouchAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

This code change my mapView height to UIScreen Height without with a nice resizing animation for 2 seconds.